# ReactJS & Javascript: Getting "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" when trying to set JSON Objects into a state hook

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Overview: I have two components: ComponentA and ComponentB, I would like to make a POST request to my API and store the returned JSON string into a useState hook, and then pass that state to componentB. In ComponentB I would like to use the .map() function to iterate through the prop's contents.

API response JSON Data Structure: `[{object: 1, name: 'bob'},{object: 2, name: 'joe'}...]`

Here is my state hook definition:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

My API call:

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("Function Called");
    fetch("/post", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formik.values),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(typeof res);
        setData(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

and my ComponentB .map() function

```
      <tbody>
        {props.responses.length > 0 ? (
          props.responses.map((response) => (
            <tr
              class={
                tableRow === "" ? (tableRow = "table-primary") : (tableRow = "")
              }
            >
              <td>{response.object}</td>
              <td>{response.name}</td>
            </tr>
          ))
        ) : (
          <tr></tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
```

whenever I make the API call I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {object, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

is it possible to set the response in the state as a JSON object and pass it to ComponentB? If so what am I doing wrong?

Or do I need to pass it off as a string and then JSON.parse() in ComponentB? (the only problem with this is that JS throws a cors error, why is that?

Comment: A lot of your description does not match up. First, you mention you are using a state named `data`, but then you are calling `setPrediction`. Then you said the API is supposed to return something like `[{object: 1, name: 'bob'}, ...]`, but you are accessing `response.day`, `response.time`. Can you clear that up?

Comment: You're trying to use map on an object instead of an array. Try `Object.entries(object).map( [a, b] => codeHere)`

Comment: @MatthewKwong sorry about that tried changing the code up a little bit so it isn't exactly what I have in mine but great catch, I've changed it!

Comment: @JoelHager that will only affect it after I've set the state and passed the data to componentB right?

Comment: Read the error. You can't map over an object with .map(). It's gonna throw an error. Use Object.entries(props.responses) and let me know what happens.

Comment: @JoelHager I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but the error is not coming from ComponentB .map() function, it's coming from ComponentA when trying to set the JSON object in the state hook. on the setData(res); line

Comment: Post the entire error code.  Console log a `typeof` on the response in Component B `console.log(typeof props.responses)`. It really does sound like you're trying to iterate over an object with map, which you cannot.  The reason it's only happening when you're calling it is that the response is then an object (not null). Then it is trying to map and failing (You can't map an object).

Comment: @JoelHager Hey I got it fixed, I'll post the answer tomorrow, Stay tuned if you're interested!

Comment: Did it have to do with iterating over an Object with map? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @JoelHager Yeah it did, I ended up moving the content from ComponentB to ComponentA. The way I was calling each object iteration in the .map function and its child element was incorrect. I'm trying to figure out if I can get it working without having ComponentB in ComponentA though, but for now that works.

Comment: Post the code and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Error tell you that you try to put whole JS object in JSX markup, you can't do that.
Just look what you getting from API and how you trying to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving component B inside Component A. The reason, I believe is that when the browser requested data from the backend, the browser wants to keep the data within its domain, so it throws a cors error when it passes the data from the browser to Component B which would be inside the virtual DOM, not yet rendered in the browser. So it's not an error thrown by the interaction of the components but by the interaction of the browser and the ReactJS server. The way to go about this is not to pass the entire state, but instead to pass individual props.